# Can't use pointer as a default template parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I am trying to use default raw pointer as a default template parameter. I read that non type template parameters are restricted to integral types, enums, pointers and references. With references I had no issues, but when I tried to use pointer I am facing such error:

```cpp
error: non-type template argument of type 'Engine *' is not a constant expression.
```

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Engine
{
public:
    void startEngine()
    {
        m_started = true;
        cout << "Engine started!" << endl;
    }
private:
    bool m_started = false;
};

template<typename T, T* DEFAULT>
class Car
{
public:
    explicit Car(const uint64_t uid) : m_uid(uid), engine(DEFAULT)
    {
        engine->startEngine();
    }

private:
    uint64_t m_uid;
    T* engine;
};

namespace
{
    std::shared_ptr<Engine> engine = std::make_shared<Engine>();
    Engine* e = engine.get();
}

int main()
{
    Car<Engine, e> lambo(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The only restriction as I see now is that second template argument needs to have static storage duration and external or internal linkage but the code fits these requirements. Appreciate any help.

Comment: No `engine.get()` is not declared to return a constant.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès even it it was, it still wouldn't make it a constant expression.

Comment: @SergeyA sure but not being marked as is a sign it should not considered as. You're right I would have mean constexpr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

non-type template arguments must be a constant expression:

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
>   converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the
>   template-parameter.

---

Perhaps you can workaround this making the object you point has static storage duration and linkage ([see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments)):

> For pointers to objects, the template arguments have to designate the
>   address of a complete object with static storage duration and a
>   linkage (either internal or external), or a constant expression that
>   evaluates to the appropriate null pointer or std::nullptr_t value.

Example:

```
namespace{
    Engine e;
}

int main(){
    Car<Engine, &e> lambo(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

As with any non-type template parameter, a pointer template parameter has to be known at compile time, or, in C++ Standard parlance, be a constant expression. And your pointer is not - compiler has no way of knowing what this address going to be when the program is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because argument must be constant expression.

So enforce constant evaluation with:

```
namespace
{
    Engine ee; 
}

int main()
{
    Car<Engine, &ee> lambo(0);
```

Comment: There is a difference between constant and constant expression.

Comment: the shared pointer stuff is not longer used and creates a second instance. Should be removed from your example.

Comment: This code will call destructor two times which produces UB.